# Как достать строку из массива который является значением ключа объекта?

Tags: javascript, массивы, циклы, объекты

```js
// Программа поиска операторов мобильной связи Украины
"use strict";
// Создаем объект с значениями ключей-массивами(коды операторов) 
var mobile = {
  Kyivstar: ["039", "067", "068", "096", "097", "098"],
  Vodafone: ["050", "066", "095", "099"],
  Lifecell: ["063", "093"],
  Intertelecom: ["094"],
  PEOPLEnet: ["092"],
  TriMob: ["091"]
}
// Запрашиваем у пользователя номер мобильного телефона
var user = prompt("Введите номер мобильного телефона в формате: 000 1112233", "");
// Получаем доступ к первым 3-м индексам user
var x = user.substr(0, 3);
// Прогоняем в цикле все ключи
for (var key in mobile) {
  var arr = mobile[key];
  // Проходимся по всем массивам
  var check = arr.forEach(function (item, i, arr) {
    if (x === item) {
      //Выводим пользователю результат
      alert("Вас приветствует " + key);
    } 
  }); 
}
```

Задача была такая:

Создать объект, который содержит названия и коды мобильных операторов. Пользователь вводит номер телефона и получает информацию о своем операторе.

Я не совсем уверен в правильности решения данной задачи.
Вроде все работает, а правильно ли?

Comment: Нет  проверок на введенные данные: кол-во символов, цифры/не цифры. Так же код ничего не сообщает, если введен телефон, оператора, которого нет в списке. А так, все работает

Comment: И надо break поставить, если найден оператор, дальше ведь нет смысла цикл продолжать.

Comment: По поводу проверки, может Вам подойдет, я у себя на сайте сделал так: даю пользователю ввести телефон как угодно, без форматов. Затем регулярным выражением форматирую строку, оставляя только цифры. И  теперь, (если цифр 11, а первая 7 или 8)  - берем 3 цифры начиная со 2-й. Если 10 - просто первые 3 цифры. Ну а если цифр не 10 или 11 - написать "неправильный ввод".

Comment: @VladSpirin Удалил коммент, так как он не относится к данному вопросу. Уведомил -- прочитано - удалил.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вставил из старой проверки своей с сайта, может пригодится:

```js
// Создаем объект с значениями ключей-массивами(коды операторов) 
var mobile = {
  Kyivstar: ["039", "067", "068", "096", "097", "098"],
  Vodafone: ["050", "066", "095", "099"],
  Lifecell: ["063", "093"],
  Intertelecom: ["094"],
  PEOPLEnet: ["092"],
  TriMob: ["091"]
}
// Запрашиваем у пользователя номер мобильного телефона
var user = prompt("Введите номер мобильного телефона", "");

var x;
var y = -1;
user = getTelNums(user);

switch (user.length) {
  case 10:
    y = 0;
    break;
  case 11:
    y = 1;
    break;
  default:
    alert('неверный формат');
    break;
}

if (y >= 0) {
  // Получаем доступ к первым 3-м индексам user
  var x = user.substr(y, 3);
  // Прогоняем в цикле все ключи
  var op = "Неизвестный оператор";
  for (var key in mobile) {
    var arr = mobile[key];
    // Проходимся по всем массивам
    var check = arr.forEach(function(item, i, arr) {
      if (x === item) {
        op = key;
        return;
      }
    });
  }
  //Выводим пользователю результат
  alert('Вас приветствует '+op);
}

function getTelNums(telStr) {
  var regexpNums = /\d/g;
  var regexpTel = /^([7|8]{0,1}0\d{2})?\d{7}$/;
  var resultTel = "";
  var checkNums = telStr.match(regexpNums); // из строки пользователя получаем массив цифр
  if (checkNums) {
    // если массив не пустой
    // сделаем из него строку:
    for (var j = 0; j < checkNums.length; j++) resultTel += checkNums[j];
    // проверим, телефон ли это:
    if (!regexpTel.test(resultTel)) {
      resultTel = "";
    }
  }
  return resultTel;
}
```