# Проверка телефонного номера

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Требуется, чтобы строка проходила проверку телефона, а так же, чтобы не проходили пробелы (/^\s+$/)

Такой код работает

```
regExp = /^((8|\+7)[\- ]?)?(\(?\d{3}\)?[\- ]?)?[\d\- ]{7,10}$/;
if( valnospace.length > 0 && !valnospace.match( regExp ) ) {
                                  error.type.push('phone');
}
```

На таком форма виснет. Что тут не так?

```
regExp = /^((8|\+7)[\- ]?)?(\(?\d{3}\)?[\- ]?)?[\d\- ]{7,10}$/;
    if( valnospace.length > 0 && (!valnospace.match( regExp ) || valnospace.match( /^\s+$/ ))) {
                                      error.type.push('phone');
}
```

Может быть, такую задачу проще решить по-другому, через trim или расширение regExp?

Comment: добавьте в вопрос несколько примеров допустимых и недопустимых строк с телефонами

Comment: Мне кажется, что самый лучший способ это не позволять вводить номер телефона в формате отличном от разрешённого. Различными плагинами можно помочь пользователю ввести в нужном формате. Вот только вопрос: речь идёт об API или о html-форме?

Comment: Lexx918, все недопустимые, кроме /^\s+$/, уже отсекает regExp

Comment: А вот пришить туда пробелы не получилось через ||

Comment: Летит много спама в виде того, что пользователь ставит один или неск пробелов вместо номера телефона

Comment: зачем проверять длину и пробелы, если у вас задано конкретное выражение для цифр?

Comment: Летит много спама в виде " " или "       " вместо номера телефона, такое надо исключить

Comment: а, не заметил пробелы в паттерне. сделайте по крайней мере трим, и проверьте длину. два условия то излишни все равно.

Comment: Друзья, всем огромное спасибо за участие. Выяснила, что regExp написан верно, и сам по себе пробелы исключает. Только в коде уже было вредительское выражение replace. Кстати regExp отлажено четко, берите на заметку https://habrahabr.ru/post/110731/

Comment: так то это выражение от 7 до 10 пробелов пропускает, ну или цифру и 7 пробелов и т.п.

Comment: teran, абсолютно точно. А как это можно устранить?

Comment: @Наташа Посмотрите [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/758263/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%8f%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0), в ответе есть то что вы ищите.

Comment: Попробуйте [`/^(?!\s+$)(?:(?:8|\+7)[-\s]?)?(?:\(?\d{3}\)?[-\s]?)?[\d\s-]{7,10}$/`](https://regex101.com/r/prFCRx/1).

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогла:

```
^(?!\s+$)(?:(?:8|\+7)[-\s]?)?(?:\(?\d{3}\)?[-\s]?)?[\d\s-]{7,10}$
```

[RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/nKk600/1)

Answer (score 0):

У меня такая стоит проверка. Попробуйте ее:

```
^(\+7|7|8)?[\s\-]?\(?[489][0-9]{2}\)?[\s\-]?[0-9]{3}[\s\-]?[0-9]{2}[\s\-]?[0-9]{2}$
```