# Преобразовать номер телефона к виду +7(000)000-00-00

Tags: javascript

Есть клиентская база, в которую заносятся номера в формате:

```
0000000000
```

Нужен скрипт, который преобразует в:

```
"+7(000)000-00-00"
```

Поле, в которое заносятся номера, именуется как: `$line['f5091']`.

Пробовал так:

```
const numberValueReduced = `$line['f5091']` => {
    return phone.replace('/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{2})$/iu', '+7 ($1) $2-$3-$4', $int);
};
```

Не вышло.

Comment: Гляньте сюда, можно кусок вырвать из этого кода: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/758263/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%8f%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0

Comment: А по какому алгоритму 9 цифр исходного номера должны превратиться в 10? Что должно получиться из номера 987654321?

Comment: Используются только мобильные номера, РФ. Соответственно +7 просто должна приписываться автоматом.

Comment: Это не отвечает на мой вопрос. У вас в исходном формате 9 цифр. Мобильные номера в РФ 10-значные (если считать еще 7, то 11-значные). Откуда должна взяться еще одна цифра?

Comment: Да, прошу прощения, там должно быть 10 цифр, поправил.

Comment: Вы не код вопроса запускайте, а код ответа. Мне тогда ответили так и у меня это успешно работает на сайте есть и РФ и Украина и много других стран. И в вашем случае там тоже все прокатывает, как с плюсом так и без. Если уж вообще туго, тогда только на фриланс, извините, чем смог тем помог

Comment: Посмотрите еще этот вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/771464/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-2-%d1%83%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%8f?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: ```'1234567890'.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{2})/, (s, code, n1, n2, n3, n4) => `+7(${code})${n1}-${n2}-${n3}`)```

Answer (score 2):

> Пробовал так:
>
> const numberValueReduced = `$line['f5091']` => {
>       return phone.replace('/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{2})$/iu', '+7 ($1) $2-$3-$4', $int); };
>
> Не вышло.

Это очевидный копипаст из похапэ, но все же объясню, почему он не работает:

- вместо имени аргумента функции, указан строковый литерал
- первым аргументом в `replace` передаете строку с регулярным выражением (вместо самого регулярного выражения)
- флаги не нужны (`i` - у числовых символов нет регистра; `u` - только если входная строка содержит юникод-последовательности)
- зачем-то передаете в `reduce` третий аргумент

---

Пример кода:

```js
const numberValueReduced = phone => {
    return phone.replace(/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{2})$/, '+7 ($1) $2-$3-$4');
};

let btnTest = document.getElementById('test'), 
    result  = document.getElementById('result'); 
btnTest.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let nmbr  = rnd(10),
      frmtd = numberValueReduced(nmbr); 
  result.innerHTML = `${nmbr}<br>${frmtd}`; 
});

function rnd(n) {
  let str = ''; 
  while (n-- > 0) 
    str += Math.floor(Math.random() * 10); 
  return str; 
}
```

```css
body,
button {
  font: 16px sans-serif; 
  text-align: center; 
}

#result {
  min-height: 70px; 
  margin-top: 30px; 
  font-size: 20px; 
}

#test {
  width: 250px; height: 35px;
  border: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase; 
  background-color: #44d; color: #fff; 
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px -2px #0007;  
}
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
<button id="test">Случайный номер</button>
```