# маска для ввода номера телефона чистый javascript

Tags: javascript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]помогите написать маску такого формата +7 (999) 999-99-99 без стороних библиотек

нужно чтобы символы ')', '(', '-', '-' нельзя было удалить, и чтобы курсор в инпут был в позиции

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Гляньте тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/758353/262779 и тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/808834/262779

Comment: Дубликат: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/808834/262779

Comment: Дубликат: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/771464/262779

Comment: Зачем задавать 10000 и 1 вопрос, который уже был раскрыт в этом сообществе? Прежде чем задавать вопрос воспользуйтесь строкой поиска на сайте, если не найдёте, то можете задать вопрос. Но убедитесь в том, что он соответствует всем правилам сообщества.

Comment: @L.F.C., не дубликат. Преобразовать и сделать маску - это не одно и то же.

Comment: @meine, ну так дай ссылку?

Comment: @Qwertiy ок, ну по ссылкам которые я дал написать не сложно, если конечно не полная лень. В любом случае закрывать надо, причина в тревогах для этого есть

Comment: @L.F.C., нет причины. Вопрос полностью понятен и это никакое не домашнее задание. И вообще, с какой стати закрывать нормальный вопрос?

Comment: @Qwertiy ТС хоть бы потрудился минимальные наработки выложить. Как-то правила получаются размытые, одни вопросы прокатывают, другие нет. Я уже терятся стал.