# Маска номера +7 в джаваскрипт

Tags: javascript

Есть поле ввода номера телефона.

Формат вводимых данных +7 ХХХ ХХХ ХХ ХХ люди вводят +7 8 ХХХ ХХХ ХХ ХХ
мне нужно в текстовом поле при условии что первая цифра будет - 8 
Удалять её.

Как это реализовать?

Comment: Уверены что именно это нужно? Так как есть регионы где номера +7 8XX XXX XX XX. это норма

Comment: У меня множество номеров вида `+7 (8XX) XXX-XX-XX` (например, СПБ - `+7 (812)`). Думаю, что Вы должны принимать только 10 цифр, после чего подставлять `+7`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Преобразовать номер телефона к виду +7(000)000-00-00](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/808834/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d1%83-7000000-00-00)

Comment: Ещё дубликат: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/959834/262779 и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/771464/262779 и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/758353/262779

Answer (score 1):

```html
<form action="POST">
  <input type='tel' id='tel' pattern="^\+7\s?[0-7|9]?[0-9]{2}\s?[0-9]{3}\s?[0-9]{2}\s?[0-9]{2}">
  <label for='tel'>Формат: +7 ХХХ ХХХ ХХ ХХ</label>
</form>
```

Решается вставкой паттерна. Он не пропустит номер, начинающийся с 8